# CSS display property

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a horizontal nav bar and my links are lining up diagonally instead of horizontally. There are also bullets showing up by the links too.

Here is my HTML:

```
<nav id="site" class="body">
<ul>
  <li id="meet"><a href="meet.html">Meet the Staff</a></li>
  <li id="conditions"><a href="conditions.html">Conditions</a></li>
  <li id="info"><a href="info.html">Patient Information</a></li>
  <li id="billing"><a href="billing.html">Billing & Insurance</a></li>
  <li id="contact"><a id="right" href="https://painandspinecenter.myezyaccess.com">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

My CSS

```
nav a {
color: #ffffff;
  font-size:13px;
  list-style:none;
  text-decoration:none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }

nav li a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  height: 44px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  padding-top:10px;
  width: 157px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-decoration:none;
  }

nav li a#right {
  border-right: none;
    text-align:top;
  }
```

The website is painandspinecenter.net

any help would be GREATLY APPRECIATED!

Comment: I can't make a complete answer now, but it probably has to do with there not being enough horizontal space, so each link is wrapping to the next line, but getting pushed slightly by the previous, making it diagonal. Also, to remove the bullet points do `list-style:none;` for the `ul`

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking. Is it: http://jsfiddle.net/p30ercuu/1/

Comment: add this line in your stylesheet.css (as per your site) - `nav ul li {float: left; list-style: none;}`, because you are using `float: left;` on `a`  instead of `li` and you should remove that from `a`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you wanted. See the fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/fyw435h3/

You were missing this from your CSS

```
nav li{
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: If that is what you're looking for, please select the check mark next to my answer to mark it correct.

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors that consist in using your A tags as block elements when you should have benn using your LI tags, consider changing your CSS to the following:

```css
#site {
    background:#069
}
nav a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size:13px;
    list-style:none;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    height: 44px;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    padding-top:10px;
    width: 140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-decoration:none;
}
nav li a#right {
    border-right: none;
    text-align:top;
}
```

```html
<nav id="site" class="body">
    <ul>
        <li id="meet"><a href="meet.html">Meet the Staff</a>
        </li>
        <li id="conditions"><a href="conditions.html">Conditions</a>
        </li>
        <li id="info"><a href="info.html">Patient Information</a>
        </li>
        <li id="billing"><a href="billing.html">Billing & Insurance</a>
        </li>
        <li id="contact"><a id="right" href="https://painandspinecenter.myezyaccess.com">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```